# How to write to an existing excel file without overwriting cell format with pandas(engine=openpyxl)?

Tags: pandas, export-to-excel, openpyxl

I wanted to write large set of data into existing excel. I referred to following link and verified the write function.
[How to write to an existing excel file without breaking formulas with openpyxl?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20262448/how-to-write-to-an-existing-excel-file-without-breaking-formulas-with-openpyxl)
However, this function **overwrote my cell format**. For example, my target excel has cell boarders for all sheets. But the newly written row is in blank background (w/o cell boarder). Also, I've already formatted some cells to be 'Currency' but with openpyxl output Excel, all cells became 'General' format.

How can I write to an existing excel file without any change of the cell format?

Thank you all.

[Original excel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ihgqC.png)

[With written contents](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yTUZQ.png)

Code to set up Excel Application

```
workbook = load_workbook(OutputFile,data_only=True)
writer =pd.ExcelWriter(OutputFile,engine='openpyxl')
writer.book = workbook
writer.sheets = dict((ws.title, ws) for ws in workbook.worksheets)
```

Code to write the results into excel

```
    FinalGen.append(FinalGenRow1)
    FinalGen.append(FinalGenRow1)
    df = pd.DataFrame(FinalGen)
    df.to_excel(writer,sheet_name='Test',startrow =3 ,startcol =0,index = False, header = False)
```

Comment: what is your openpyxl version? Check [this question and answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40610166/fill-in-pd-data-frame-into-existing-excel-sheet-using-openpyxl-v2-3-2)...

Comment: This is possible with openpyxl. Please show your code so far.

Comment: Code added. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Hi MaxU. My version is 2.4.1

Answer (score 0):

The only solution I found is to set the cells format by each cell instead of by column. See this post for details. [Preserve cell format with openpyxl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40596581/use-style-of-column-for-new-cells-in-openpyxl/40604618#40604618)